# How to get active aurelia fetch ajax calls count

Tags: aurelia

When a site is using jquery/XMLhttp requests we were able to get active ajax calls in the backend using jQuery.active. But when a site is using aurelia fetch for ajax calls, how to get number of active fetch calls in the backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a wrapper on my `fetch` calls that increments a variable before each call and then decreases it in the `.then` code block. That seems to work well.

**Sample code:**

```
getData(url) {
  // Http Fetch Client to retreive data (GET)
  this.apiCalls += 1;
  console.log("getData from API: " + url);
  return this.httpClient.fetch(url, {
    credentials: 'include'
  }).then(response => {
    this.apiCalls -= 1;
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw Error(response.statusText);
    }
    return response.json();
  }).catch(error => {
    this.apiCalls -= 1;
    console.log(error);
    return null;
  });
}
```

Comment: can you please share that. Actually I am trying to use this in selenium on a aurelia site. But I am not able to get that Fetch requests  processed in the backend.Tried by injecting the javascript code into site but not able to get aurelia fetch ajax count.

Comment: Sure.  I just updated my response.  So instead of calling fetch directly, all of my pages call this `getData()` routine which makes the call and also does some pre-processing by converting the response to json (specific to my context, maybe not helpful for you).  You can always examine `apiCalls` to see how many calls are active.  I have another parallel routine for `postData()` with similar layout.

Comment: Thank you Starky. In my organisation, dev team are not ready to add a wrapper, Is there any other workaround which can help to inject some script at page level and find any active fetch calls/requests.Using XMLHTTP requests used this code to inject in site.

Comment: (function() {
    var oldOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
    window.openHTTPs = 0;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, pass) {
      window.openHTTPs++;
      this.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
          if(this.readyState == 4) {
            window.openHTTPs--;
          }
        }, false);
      oldOpen.call(this, method, url, async, user, pass);
    }
  })(XMLHttpRequest);

Comment: is there any similar way we can do for fetch requests too so that in browser console at any point of time can we get count of request being processed.

Comment: @LStarky I think you have a small bug in your code: in the first `then()` you decrease your counter. If the response is not ok, you throw an exception which goes to the `catch()`. In there, you decrease it another time. I propose you should decrease the counter in a last `then()`.

Comment: It's working for me right now... in my experience, the `.then()` is not called if there was an error invoking fetch.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by creating a singleton/global value and then configuring the client with [interceptors](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/fetch-client/latest/http-services/3). There you can hook into all your requests/responses. Modify the singleton there, and import the singleton to any viewmodel where it's needed. Both the fetch-client and httpclient supports this.

```
let client = new HttpClient();
client.configure(x => {
    x.withInterceptor({
      request(message) {
        singleton.activeConnections++;
        return message;
      },

      response(message) {
        singleton.activeConnections--;
        return message;
      }
    });
  });
```